# width and height of Widget inside __init__ method

Tags: python, kivy

I want to build a custom Widget for a dice rolling game.
I am setting a number `NumericProperty` that will have values from 1 to 6.
I want the widget to be drawn according to this property.
I was drawing the rectangle in the kivy file using the `min(self.width, self.height)` for a side and it works ok. But because the dots needs more 
processing I decided to do it in the python file, inside the `__init__` method. The problem is that when I try to use the width and height of the widget in order to position the dots correctly, I get 100px for width and height no mather the size of the window. (My widget is the root)
I was reading the documentation and there explaines that 100px is the default size of the Widget and that inside "**init**" it is not yet updated to the size of the parent. 
Now I would like to know if is there another place where I can draw the dots and the size of the widget is already updated. I saw that in the kivy file I'm getting the behaivior I want but I'm not able to use the .kv file to draw the dots because I'm not very versed in the kivy language.
Can someone help?

```
# main.py
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import Line

class DiceWidget(Widget):
    number = NumericProperty(random.randint(1, 6))
    d_width = NumericProperty()
    dots_map = {
        1: ('c'),
        2: ('bl', 'tr'),
        3: ('bl', 'c', 'tr'),
        4: ('bl', 'br', 'tl', 'tr'),
        5: ('bl', 'br', 'c', 'tl', 'tr'),
        6: ('bl', 'br', 'cl', 'cr', 'tl', 'tr'),
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.d_width = min(self.width, self.height)
        self.dots_pos = {
            'tl': (self.d_width*0.2, self.d_width*0.8),
            'tr': (self.d_width*0.8, self.d_width*0.8),
            'cl': (self.d_width*0.2, self.d_width*0.5),
            'c' : (self.d_width*0.5, self.d_width*0.5),
            'cr': (self.d_width*0.8, self.d_width*0.5),
            'bl': (self.d_width*0.2, self.d_width*0.2),
            'br': (self.d_width*0.8, self.d_width*0.2),
        }
        self.draw_dots()

    def draw_dots(self):
        positions = self.dots_map[self.number]
        with self.canvas:
            for position in positions:
                x, y = self.dots_pos[position]
                Line(circle=(x, y, 8))

    def roll(self):
        number.set(random.randint(1,6))

class DiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DiceWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DiceApp().run()



# dice.kv
<DiceWidget>:
    canvas:
        Line:
            rectangle:
                [self.x, self.y, min(self.width, self.height), 
                                 min(self.width, self.height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the events `on_width` and/or `on_height` inside your class, but since you want both, just wait for `on_size` e.g.

```
class DiceWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # elided

    def on_size(self, sender, value):
        width = value[0]
        height = value[1]
```